# One-way data binding is not really one-way for passed objects in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Basically, if you pass an object (not a primitive) to a component's @input one-way data binding () is actually a two-way data binding as all changes to "bar" made in my-component will obviously applied in component's parent's bar.
What's the reference way to deal with references to objects in components? Use only primitives? Is there a way to make truly one-way binding?

Comment: Yes because objects reference do not change (objects are mutable). If the same object ref changes somewhere, it will change everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

That's not related to data binding. Objects are passed by reference by data binding. If the reference is used to modify the instance, every other location that holds the same location will see the change.

Perhaps you want to clone the object before you pass it around.